# Find the list of all the customers with a name that contains a letter between two letters

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

my table is here 
customers

```
CREATE TABLE `customers` (
  `customer_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `account_num` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `lname` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fname` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mi` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `address1` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `address2` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `address3` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `address4` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `postal_code` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `region_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `phone1` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `phone2` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `birthdate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `marital_status` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `yearly_income` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `gender` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `total_children` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `num_children_at_home` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `education` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `member_card` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `occupation` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `houseowner` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `num_cars_owned` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I have to find out
Find the list of all the customers with a name that contains a letter between “a” and “d” as the second letter

my query is not working as needed

```
SELECT * 
FROM   customers
WHERE  fname  REGEXP '^[A-D]';
```

Comment: Don't know much about regex, but you could eventually do it like `where SUBSTR(fname, 2, 1) in ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')`

Comment: yes you are right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM   customers
WHERE  SUBSTR(fname,2,1) REGEXP '^[A-D]';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```
SELECT * 
FROM   customers
WHERE  fname  REGEXP '^.[A-Da-d]{1}';
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4fd628/1)

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieved by simple LIKE statement instead of using regex.

```
SELECT * 
FROM   customers
WHERE  upper(fname)  LIKE '_[A-D]%';
```